# I'm confused... Should I ask this in serverfault?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [Setting up a VPN server for LAN access over the internet using OpenVPN in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1599394/setting-up-a-vpn-server-for-lan-access-over-the-internet-using-openvpn-in-linux)

Should I consider asking this in serverfault?? This question is involved in networking...

I thought I should ask here because it's a newbie question and not professionally related to networking.

Comment: How you setup OpenVPN on a Linux machine is within scope here at Super User.